# What designer statements are there for why there is a lack of weapon variety in 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, designer-reasons

I was taking a look at the 4th edition weapons page and that thing is massive, with relatively well-known weapons like Falchions, Bastard Swords, and parrying daggers. Yet in 5th edition, they've omitted quite a number of these weapon selections, and no core book has added to this list yet.

There's also the curious case of the only non-light finesse weapon, the Rapier (discounting the whip, which generally is not a viable choice for combat), which also happens to be the only top tier choice for melee Dex combatants.

I feel like this was an intentional choice on the part of Wizards of the Coast. I am hoping for insight into designer intent. **Are there any designer statements as to why the weapon variety is very limited in this game?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because designer intent/reasons. https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/43856

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### The weapon list reduction reflects the overarching design goal *to make the game simpler*

> [It’s part of **our overall move** to make the game simpler.](http://www.therobotsvoice.com/2014/11/20_questions_with_wizards_of_the_coasts_dd_develop.php)

The above quote by Jeremy Crawford is actually about a different feature of the game (how proficiency and proficiency bonuses fit into D&D 5e) from a 2014 interview, but it captures the D&D 5e design philosophy.

During development, a variety of more complex ideas came and went before the game's final release.  Here is an example involving weapons [from developer Mike Mearls in a reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/2l69tp/ama_mike_mearls_codesigner_of_dd_5_head_of_dd_rd/):

> **Q: What was your favorite concept from the 5e playtest cycle which got left on the cutting room floor?**
>
> A: {one deleted} ... here's another one.  At one point, each martial weapon had a special maneuver built into it. It was a cool idea, but it proved too complex at the table. Were I to do it again, I'd look at using the 4e weapon categories, tying the special maneuvers to those categories, and giving only certain characters access to them (fighters can use any of them, other classes more limited).

#### Bottom Line: more simplicity

D&D 5e was by design intended to be leaned out and stripped down a great deal as compared to some previous editions.  The weapons table is but one reflection of that design philosophy.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thx for format upgrade. Looks better.

Answer (score 8):

D&D Philosophy is that there are few if any rules only rulings.

***PHB 5E p.146*** states:

> The Weapons table shows the most common weapons used in the worlds of D&D

Note that it specifically says "common." Not all. The Players's Handbook is simplifying the point of entry, not restricting what you and your table can allow.

This can be found reinforced on ***PHB 5E p.78***:

> Certain monasteries use specialized forces of the monk weapons. For example, you might use a club that is two lengths of wood connected by a short chain (called a nunchaku) or a sickle with a shorter, straighter blade (called a kama). Whatever name you use for a monk weapon, you can use the game statistics provided for the weapon in chapter 5, "Equipment."

Then in the ***Dungeon Master's Guide, p41***

> Wuxia Weapon Names
>
> Having players refer to a tetsubo or a katana rather than a greatclub or a longsword can enhance the flavor of a wuxia campaign. The Wuxia Weapon Names table lists alternative names for common weapons from the Player's Handbook and identifies their real-world cultural origins.

I think it would be very fair to say a Falchion would be similar in quality to a Scimitar while a Bastard Sword would probably be closest to a Long Sword, though if you're playing a smaller character maybe having it function more like a 2H would make more sense. It's your game, your character, and your weapon.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast added it, thanks for the info